# Installing MySQLdb windows for Python 2.5

Tags: python, mysql

I have seen this issue come up a lot on these discussion boards but I am still having trouble finding an answer.  I am trying to install MySQLdb for Python 2.5 on my Windows Vista machine.  I grabbed the installation file from this link

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/reviews/

I then opened my Windows command prompt and entered "cd MYSQL-python-1.2.3".

I then entered "python setup.py build"

At this point, it gives me an error: "File setup.py, line 5, in module ImportError: No module named setuptools"

Can anyone give me some guidance on what I should do next? I have searched the web for days regarding this issue.....I have seen several posts saying that there is no good solution for this when running Python 2.5 on Windows.  I hope this isn't the case.  Thanks!

-Pete

Comment: You can get "setuptools" by installing "distribute": http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for that suggestion!  I installed "distribute" and was able to run "python setup.py build" and then "python setup.py install" without errors.  However, when I run "python import MySQLdb" an error tells me "no module named _mysql".  Any more suggestions? Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can install first the setuptools for python 2.5, you can find it here http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
search for where it says:setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.3.exe (md5)

After you install this, then try again installing mysqldb